# Send array value in a URL parameter

Tags: php, arrays, dynamic

I'm having issues building a proper URL parameter sent to a service. I need to send dynamic query results in one parameter. Here's what I have reached so far:

```
<a href="https://serviceurl/?language=EN&variable1=<?php 
$mobiles = array();
while($row_query = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
  $data = $row_query['rowwithvalues'];
  $myArray = implode(',', $data);
  foreach($myArray as $my_Array){
    echo $my_Array; 
  }
}
?>&variable2=Hello">Test</a>
```

The above returns a blank value for variable1 in the url.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does your query successfully execute? Also `mysql_fetch_assoc()` is depreciated, and also does not execute a query. See [`mysqli_fetch_assoc()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)

Comment: Can you add debug print in your script and see which command been executed?

Comment: You have an array of variables to send or a variable that is an array and you want to send that array in 1 variable?

Comment: Please change `implode` to `explode` as the first return string and you need an array

Comment: `mysql_fetch_assoc` — **Danger** this function has been obsoleted for *years* and isn't available in any version of PHP that still gets security fixes.

Comment: Thank you so much dWinder I have tried again and explode worked! How can I mark your answer as the correct answer?

Comment: @MonaAbdelHady I un-delete my post - you may mark it as accepted (the "v" mark at the left of the answer) - glad it helped!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you calling `$myArray = implode(',', $data);` it makes `$myArray` **string** from [implode doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php):

> Returns a string containing a string representation of all the array elements in the same order, with the glue string between each element.

So you cannot loop on it - I guess you wanted to use [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php). Try this:

```
<a href="https://serviceurl/?language=EN&variable1=
<?php 
    while($row_query = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        $data = $row_query['rowwithvalues'];
        $myArray = explode(',', $data);
        foreach($myArray as $my_Array){
            echo $my_Array; 
        }
    }
?>&variable2=Hello">Test</a>
```

Comment: Same results with explode. Thanks